# How can I partially update an embedded document using Spring Data MongoDB's MongoTemplate?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Please can some one tell me how can I update a record in an embedded document? Here is my document structure:

```
{
  "_id":"1000",
  "event_name":"Some name",  
  "tracks":
   [
     {
         "id" : "100"
         "title" : "Test title",
     },
     {
         "id" : "101",
         "title" : "Test title 2",
     }
  ]
}
```

I want to update title of track having id 101. As related to [my question as there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24802391/how-to-insert-embedded-document-using-spring-data-mongodb-mongotemplate).

Answer (score 1):

I am able to solve my problem by using the following piece of code

```
MongoConverter converter = mongoTemplate.getConverter();

DBObject newTrackRec = (DBObject)converter.convertToMongoType(track);

Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("_id").is(track.getEventId()).and("tracks._id").is(track.getId()));

Update update = new Update().set("tracks.$", newTrackRec);

mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, Event.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically follow the instructions of the [MongoDB reference documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array) and translate that into the Spring Data MongoDB query and update APIs:

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query.*;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.*;

Track track = …;
String title = …;

Query query = query(
  where("id").is(track.getEventId()).
  and("tracks.id").is(track.getId()));

Update update = new Update().set("tracks.$.title", title);

mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, Event.class);
```